# Weak convergence of a Dirichlet distribution

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, weak-convergence

The Dirichlet distribution $\mathcal{D}(\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_d)$ on the simplex $\{ w \in [0,1]^{d-1}: \, \Vert w \Vert_1 \leq  1 \}$ has Lebesgue density

$$
\frac{ \Gamma(\sum_{i=1}^d \alpha_i) }{\prod_{i=1}^d \Gamma(\alpha_i)} \left(\prod_{i=1}^{d-1} w_i^{\alpha_i -1} \right)\left( 1- \sum_{i=1}^{d-1}w_i\right)^{\alpha_d-1}.
$$

**QUESTION:** Assume that, for some integer $d_0<d$, the first $d_0$ parameters $\alpha_i$ converge  to zero: would the corresponding measure converge weakly to

$$
\mu=(\otimes_{i=1}^{d_0} \delta_0) \otimes \mathcal{D}(\alpha_{d_0+1}, \ldots, \alpha_d)
$$
where $\delta_0$ is the Dirac measure at $0$?

I'm trying to exploit the usual characterisation of weak convergence in terms of convergence of $\int f(w) \mathcal{D}(\alpha_1, \ldots,\alpha_d; dw)$ to $\int f(w) \mu( dw)$ for bounded and continuous functions, but it's not clear to me how to make it work in the given setup.

**ADDENDUM:** what I can immediately see is that the univariate marginal distribution of each of the first $d_0$ components $W_i$ of a random vector with distribution $\mathcal{D}(\alpha_1, \ldots,\alpha_d)$ is $\text{Beta}(\alpha_i, \sum_{j\neq i}^d\alpha)$, whose mean and variance would converge to $0$ as $\alpha_i \to 0$: if we let $\alpha_i\equiv \alpha_{n,i}\to 0$, we thus have that $W_i \overset{p}{\to}0$. Would this help in proving the desired result?

Comment: I'd try to gather intuition from the Bayesian use of the Dirichlet distribution as a prior.